# how to conditionally create new column in dataframe based on other column values in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a julia dataframe that looks like this:

```
time    data
0        34
1        34
2        30
3        37
4        32
5        35
```

How do I create a new binary column that is `0` if `time` is less than 2 and greater than 4, and 1 if not either condition?

Like this:

```
time    data    x
0        34     0
1        34     0
2        30     1
3        37     1
4        32     1
5        35     0
```

In python, I would do something like:

```
def func(df):
    if df.time < 2 or df.time > 4:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
df['x'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia we have the beautiful [Dot Syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized) which can be gracefully applied here:

```
julia> df[!, :x] = 2 .<= df[!, :time] .<= 4     
6-element BitVector:
0
0
1
1
1
0
```

or alternatively

```
df.x = 2 .<= df.time .<= 4
```

Comment: Thank you!

I get this error:
`
ERROR: ArgumentError: syntax df[column] is not supported use df[!, column] instead
`

Comment: I switched to `julia> df[1,x] = 2 .<= df[!,time] .<= 4  ` but now get this:
' ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), ::typeof(time))
'

Comment: I'm sorry, @connor449, I updated my answer so now it should be right. Though now I'm confused, because it worked perfectly on my machine

Comment: @ginkul: The syntax `df[col]` is in old DataFrame versions and it has been replaced with the more verbose `df[!,col]` or `df[:,col]` in more recent versions of DataFrames to explicitly indicate if the data in `col` should be referenced or copied respectively (and df.col is an alias to df[!,col])